# Python3 ctypes c_char array converted to immutable bytes type?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I've defined a structure:

```
class test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('char_array', c_char * 255)]

a = test()

# prints <class 'bytes'>
print(type(a.char_array))
```

Why is this type `bytes` and not type `bytearray`?
I'm unable to change values in `char_array` because bytes doesn't support item assignment. i.e: `a.char_array[0] = 1`

This isn't the case if instead I were to use `c_int`; just curious why ctypes is converting this to a `bytes` object and not leaving it as `c_char_Array_255` like it would if it were `c_int * 255`?

How do I convert it to a `bytearray` and still modify the structure accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

Type `c_char` maps to immutable type.

Use type `c_byte` to be able to modify that. Example:

```
from ctypes import *

class test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('char_array', c_byte * 255)]

a = test()

print(type(a.char_array))
a.char_array[0]=ord('e')
a.char_array[1]=ord('x')
print(bytes(a.char_array).decode())
```

prints `ex`